# Proving tautology without using truth tables

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a statement `(P∧Q∧(R∧P⇒~Q))⇒~R` that I need to prove tautology without using truth tables.  I understand I'll be using inference rules.

Here's what I've tried so far, step by step:

```
(P∧Q∧(~(R∧P)V~Q))⇒~R
((P∧Q∧~(R∧P)) V P∧Q∧~Q))⇒~R
((P∧Q∧~(R∧P)) V P∧False))⇒~R
((P∧Q∧~(R∧P)) V False))⇒~R
(P∧Q∧~(R∧P))⇒~R
```

I'm stuck at this point, unsure of what the next step is.

Comment: What are your inference rules?

Answer (score 1):

> $\begin{align}
> (P∧Q∧(\neg(R∧P)\vee\neg Q))\to\neg R
> \\ ((P∧Q∧\neg(R∧P)) \vee P∧Q∧\neg Q))\to\neg R
> \\ ((P∧Q∧\neg(R∧P)) \vee P∧\bot))\to\neg R
> \\ ((P∧Q∧\neg(R∧P)) \vee \bot))\to\neg R
> \\ (P∧Q∧\neg (R∧P))\to\neg R
> \end{align}$

It's all good so far.  The key steps to completion is to apply DeMorgan's Negation, Distribution, and Implication Equivalence.

$$\neg (X\wedge Y) \iff \neg X\vee \neg Y
\\
X\wedge(Y\vee Z) \iff (X\wedge Y)\vee(X\wedge Z)
\\
X\to Y \iff \neg X\vee Y$$

Extra Hint: $X\wedge(Y\vee \neg X) \iff X\wedge Y$

---

That however is using boolean calculus.  Using the rules of inference would be

$\begin{array}{|ll}
(P∧Q∧(R∧P\to \neg Q))\to \neg R
\\
(P\wedge \neg(\neg Q)\wedge (R\wedge P\to (\neg Q)))\to \neg R & \text{Double Negation}
\\ (P\wedge \neg(R\wedge P))\to \neg R & \text{Modus Tollens}
\\ P\to( \neg(R\wedge P)\to \neg R) & \text{Exportation}
\\ P\to( \neg\neg R\to\neg\neg(R\wedge P)) & \text{Contraposition}
\\ P\to( R\to\neg\neg(R\wedge P)) & \text{Double Negation Elimination}
\\ P\to( R\to(R\wedge P)) & \text{Double Negation Elimination}
\\ (P\wedge R)\to (R\wedge P) & \text{Importation}
\\ (P\wedge R)\to (P\wedge R) & \text{Association}
\\ \top & \text{Tautology}
\end{array}$